# In elasticsearch(version 7.7.0) , new fields are getting mapped to type keyword by default

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Java high level rest client to interact with elastic search . I noticed that when i am trying to insert a new field , they get dynamically mapped as keywords :

```
    "fieldName": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    }
```

The issue it causes , is that i am not able to search this field . I noticed that no analyzer gets associated with keyword field , whereas other fields have analyzer = 'text_general' . I intend to store a list of list in this field(like , [["some_string"] , ["String 2 , "string 3"] , ["string 4" , "string 5" , "string 6"]]) .

How do i make my fields map like :

```
            "fieldName": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "text_general"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From elasticsearch 7.x, by default [string fields are mapped into `text` and `keyword` types](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) (if no explicit mapping is defined). You can [create your own index mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/explicit-mapping.html), according to your need, while creating the index.

But in your case, you are want to map the new field, to be of `text` type along with analyzer. For this, you can use [dynamic template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#template-variables). With this, you can map all the string fields to be of `text` type along with an `analyzer`.

Adding a working example, that will map all the string fields to be of `text` type and analyzer `"my_analyzer"` (you need to change the analyzer definition, according to your requirement)

**Index Mapping:**

```
PUT /<index-name>
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "named_analyzers": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "match": "*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In this whenever you create a new field, that field will be of `text` type and having analyzer as `my_analyzer`

**Index Data:**

```
POST /<index-name>/_doc/1
{
    "name":"multi grain bread"
}
```

Now, if you run the [Get Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html), you will see the below mapping

```
GET /<index-name>/_mapping
{
  "68734695": {
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "named_analyzers": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Vivek please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolved your issue ?

Comment: The problem i want to solve is to make the field searchable . My initial guess was that no analyzer gets associated with keyword field , and so its not searchable. But i noticed another field having same mapping and its searchable .

Comment: @Vivek `keyword` analyzer gets associated with the keyword field. That means you can search for exact search using the `keyword` subfield. Can you explain what exactly are you trying to search ?

Comment: So i want to store a list of list in the field(like , [["some_string"] , ["String 2 , "string 3"] , ["string 4" , "string 5" , "string 6"]] .

If i search "som" , i want the this document in the search result